# Meteor invite and create user

Tags: mongodb, model, meteor

Im facing this issue for quite some time now, note this is sort of a model structuring qusetion.
i have a group collection ,that a user can create a group adding some details such a name,description, location and more.. in addition the user can invite friends to his group.
considering those friends already registered to my web app, it is simple just getting the _id of the invited friends and adding it to my group document like so:

```
{creator: ...,name:"bla bla",desc:"bla bla"... users:[ invitedFriend_id,invitedFriend_id..]
```

also im doing the reverse sight of this operation, meaning invitedFriend_id gets new value
for an array of groups like so (user document):

```
{name:"bla bla",services:{...},groups:{invited:[group_id that invited this user..],owned:[group_id this user have created]}
```

the real problem is when a user invites friends that are not registered yet, so the obvious
problem is that i save the group_id in not existing user.
i thought of checking if a user is not registered yet by checking if the email is not yet used by any user, but im afraid to overload the DB because searching in the whole users collection for a certain email seems very wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's what databases are for - right? So that you can efficiently search the whole data for a given value.

Assuming you're using Meteor accounts, this query will help:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': email})
```

If there is an user with a given `email`, this will return that user. Otherwise it will return `null`.

Comment: haha liked your answer...i guess this is what ill do.as for the use of databases, because im not a server-side developer im afraid doing expensive operations on the DB im not so familiar with DB's DB limitations and cons

Comment: Prefer "Meteor.users.findOne({"emails.address":email}) over use of $elemMatch as its faster for this simple query.